# Sorting elements alphabetically then numerically

Tags: java, sorting

Quick question, just say I have a list/collection of nodes made up of hostnames or IP's. I now want to sort them alphabetically then numerically so thinking using .sort() call is right way to go?

Answer (score 2):

If nodes implement `java.lang.Comparable`, you can define custom ordering. If you can not change/modify the node class, then you can implement `java.util.Comparator`, and use `Collection.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`
Effective Java from Bloch has excellent section on this topic.

Comment: Cheers for help, just had to refactor arraylist to sorted list using call.

> listname.SortedArray();

Answer (score 1):

just implement a `Comperator` and use `Arrays.sort()` as you assumed

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class

```
class Foo {
int no;
String val;
}
```

and

```
Collections.sort(listOfFoo,new Comparator<Foo>(){public int compare(Foo f1, Foo f2){
//your logic goes here
}});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be compare() and not compareTo() ?

Comment: @amit , yes was confused between `Comparable` and this

Comment: Cheers for help, just had to refactor arraylist to sorted list using call.

> listname.SortedArray();